# Sockets in OSX Lion with xcode4?

Tags: macos, sockets, xcode4, osx-lion

I want to create an TCP connection (client) with sockets in OSX. I'm using xcode 4.

Which class should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would take a look at CocoaAsyncSocket, which is open source and available at:

http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/

They have very good examples as to how to use the framework, and it's much better than dealing with the C calls directly...

CocoaAsyncSocket supports TCP and UDP. The AsyncSocket class is for TCP, and the AsyncUdpSocket class is for UDP.

Comment: CocoaAsyncSocket is really the gold standard here. It's exactly what you want for low-level socket protocols.

Answer (score 2):

If you're familiar with BSD sockets and would prefer to use them, check out [this page](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2002/12/26/cocoa.html) (kind of outdated).
`#include <sys/socket.h>`

However, as MTurner mentioned above, [CocoaAsyncSocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) is considered a better solution.